# How to fix the relative paths in action attribute in form tag (html)

Tags: html, forms, apache

[folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0uVj.png)
This is work for me (from index.html, typed akaleaf.com in browser (apache2))

```html
<form action="love512.png" method="GET">
```

But this is not (even if I have love512.png in every folder)

```html
<form action="../cgi-bin/love512.png" method="GET">
```

```html
<form action="cgi-bin/love512.png" method="GET">
```

```html
<form action="/cgi-bin/love512.png" method="GET">
```

```html
<form action="/var/www/akaleaf.com/cgi-bin/love512.png" method="GET">
```

After press the button of these 4 versions of index.html I have "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server." On first one correctly opens a love512.png image.

Every folder and file(starting with 'www' folder) have 777 access permission and chown to akaleaf(me) group

Comment: The web server generally can't access anything outside of the docroot folder, which in this case seems to be ``public_html`` (although I'd need to see the contents of ``httpd.conf`` to know for certain). That's why the only one that works is the first one.

Comment: @kmoser Thanks for reply. I have not ```httpd.conf``` file, but I have ```akaleaf.com.conf``` file (etc/apache2/sites-available) which contains the following:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@akaleaf.com
 ServerName akaleaf.com
 ServerAlias www.akaleaf.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/akaleaf.com/public_html
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is: add

```
<IfModule alias_module> 
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/var/www/akaleaf.com/cgi-bin/" 
</IfModule>
```

in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` file in some place(whatever I think)(don't forget to replace `/var/www/akaleaf.com` to path of your site root folder). 
File `akaleaf.com.conf` contains: yadi.sk/i/vQdcAhtN3S4KGQ. 
Now love512.png **doesn't work** by `cgi-bin/love512.png`(but it work in from other folders, e.g. public_html), but script `cgi-bin/story.pl` **work**, which is more better.

Answer (score 0):

The web server configuration file causes the server to have access only to the `/var/www/akaleaf.com/public_html` folder, which is why you're unable to access `love512.png` in other folders, even by providing relative paths.

Comment: okay, I changed the line `DocumentRoot /var/www/akaleaf.com/public_html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/akaleaf.com`. But ```<form action="../cgi-bin/love512.png" method="GET">``` doesn`t work.
Additionly, when I try to open the cgi-bin fodler in browser it says me "Forbidden". https://yadi.sk/i/GqFiVifF3BluKQ

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Also, what folder is your ``index.html`` file in? If it's in the ``akleaf.com folder``, your form action is wrong; it should be ``<form action="cgi-bin/love512.png" method="get">``.

Comment: `index.html` file located in `public_html` folder. Even if I move the `index.html` to `akaleaf.com` folder and change to `<form action="cgi-bin/love512.png">` it does't work

Comment: [SOLVED] Solution is: add `<IfModule alias_module> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/var/www/akaleaf.com/cgi-bin/" </IfModule>` in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` file in some place(whatever I think). File `akaleaf.com.conf` contains: https://yadi.sk/i/vQdcAhtN3S4KGQ. Now love512.png doesn't work by `cgi-bin/love512.png`, but script `cgi-bin/story.pl` work, which is more better.